# call route inside of a view in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, view, router

I know there are great deal of tutorials/information about orgaising an application using Backbone.js out there. I am creating gradually one with the aid of the those tutorials. I seem to fail understanding the concept of routers. Well, I am aware that routers are starting point(and tells the state of an app) and it's better to avoid putting more logic there.

I have one router. My app would firstly load header, footer, and main part of the page. In main part, first, I should login the user. To load the login page, I would do something like this:

```
       var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            initialize : function() {
            var headerView = new HeaderView({el:$('#header')});
            headerView.render;

            var footerView = new FooterView({el:$('#footer')});
            footerView.render;

            var loginView = new LoginView({el:$('#login')});
            loginView.render;
        },
        routes : {
            "inbox" : "inbox",
            "sentbox : "sentbox"
        },
        inbox : function() {
            // ...
        },
        sentbox : function() {
            // ...
        }
    });
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

After successful login, the mail page will be loaded. MailView has some events to show inbox, sentbox for example.

```
     events: {
        "click .inbox": "showInbox",
        "click .sentbox": "showSentbox",
      },
       showInbox : function() {
            // app.route() or app.inbox() - ?
      }
```

At this point, I want the router to show `../#inbox` and `../#sentbox` respectively. I am wondering if I should call here one of the router's method to show that in address bar. Why I am confusing is because it's said that usage of one router is better than more. If I do so, my `AppRouter` will be more complicated. Another issue is if users type the address directly, I should load that page. I think it requires to put the logic inside the *AppRouter*.

Please tell me the right approach here. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out Router.navigate() (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate)

I normally save an instance variable of my Router inside my App object, e.g.

```
var App = {
  Views: {},
  Routers: {},
  Models: {},
  data: {}

  initialize: function() {
    this.data.mainRouter = new App.Routers.MainRouter();
  }
};
```

where App.MainRouter is defined as:

```
App.Routers.MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

   routes: {
     'route1' : 'route1handler',
     'route2/:param' : 'route2handler'
   },

   ... 
});
```

Then within my view, if I want to navigate to a new route, I call:

```
App.data.mainRouter.navigate('route2/param1');
```

Comment: Note that you can call `Backbone.history.navigate` as well if your router isn't accessible from your view.

Comment: This only changes the url hash and doesnt fire the route's handler method

Comment: To fire the route's handler you have to add `{trigger: true}` as a second parameter.

Answer (score 7):

You just send the browser to the appropriate route via:

```
location.href = "#/the_route_you_want";
```

The listener within `Backbone.history` will capture the `hashChange` event and the proper view will display.

This can be done in a very simple way via HTML:

```
<a href="#/the_route_you_want">The Route You Want</a>
```

[For further reading.](http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am not actually using `<a>`. Second, what would happen if user types into address bar that url.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to also call the route function, set the trigger option to true:

```
app.navigate("help/troubleshooting", {trigger: true});
```